# Does a strictly convex and weak metrizable unit sphere of a Banach space imply separability?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want know

> If $X$ be a Banach space with strictly convex norm and a metrizable unit sphere, $S_X=\{x\in X: \|x\|=1\}$, for the weak topology.

Does a strictly convex and weak metrizable unit sphere of a Banach space imply separability? recall that

1. A Banach
   space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is said  to be  locally uniformly convex or
   locally uniformly rotund (LUR) if for all $x, x_n \in X$ satisfying
   $$\lim_{n\to
   \infty}(2\|x\|^2+2\|x_n\|^2-\|x+x_n\|^2)=0$$
   we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\|x_n-x\|=0.$
2. A Banach
   space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is said  to be strictly convex or
   rotund (R) if for all $y, x \in X$ satisfying
   $$(2\|y\|^2+2\|x\|^2-\|y+x\|^2)=0$$
   we have $x=y.$

   Thanks